# Updating an Aho-Corasick trie in the face of inserts and deletes

Tags: database, algorithm, search, data-structures, aho-corasick

All the literature and implementations I've found of Aho-Corasick are about building the entire trie beforehand from a set of phrases. However, I'm interested in ways to work with it as a mutable data structure, where it can handle occasional adds and removes without needing to rebuild the whole trie (imagine there are 1 million entries in it). It's OK if the worst case is awful, as long as the average case is close to logarithmic.

From how I figure it, the fail state for each node is another node that uses the same symbol. So if we have a hash multimap from each symbol to the list of nodes which use that symbol, we have our candidates whose fail states need updating.

Remove is straightforward. You find all other nodes which use the deleted node as a fail state and recompute their fail state. Go from the end of the string backwards, and the tree *should* still be in good shape.

Add is a bit trickier. Any node that failed to that symbol could have the new node as a better candidate. However, again it *seems* to be enough to traverse every other node with that symbol and fully recompute its fail state.

In other words, if we're adding or removing a node with symbol "A", we need to visit every other "A" node anywhere in the trie, and recompute the fail state (look for its closest ancestor with "A" as a child, or the root). This would require visiting every node for symbol "A", but in my case, that would be several orders of magnitude less than visiting every node in the trie.

Would that algorithm work, or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Visiting every node with a symbol "A" to update its fail state wouldn't be so difficult, I guess. *Finding* every such node, though, will require a linear scan of the tree, unless you keep an auxiliary data structure that maps every node by symbol. I think to do this update efficiently will require O(n) extra space, where n is the number of nodes in your trie.

Comment: I think this is going to be more than just updating the fail states. Consider removing the string "the" from the list of matched terms. But you still have to match "their," "they," "them," "other," etc. And, yeah ... adding gets pretty tricky. I've never seen an article on updating an Aho-Corasick trie in-place, which leads me to believe that this is a pretty hard problem.

Comment: @JimMischel Yes, I expect it to take a bit more memory, my main concern is correctness and time complexity. The question is whether there is a sequence of operations that would leave the trie in a bad state. In that particular case, you could remove the "the" output from the "e" node, but leave the node intact as a non-output node, as long as you're not compressing nodes. My intuition says that would work fine, but I'm not certain; there could be cases where a node would need to move, which would mean other seemingly-unrelated fail states could be wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went ahead and implemented it and it *seems* to be working. A somewhat nicer description of the algorithm, including pictures: https://burningmime.gitlab.io/setmatch/implementation-overview.html#supporting-add-remove-in-an-aho-corasick-trie

For posterity (and per StackOverflow policy), I've copied it here:

> It supports modification (add/remove) instead of being built all at
>   once from a pre-set dictionary. This isn't mentioned in any literature
>   about it, and all the open-source implementations I've seen of it have
>   followed in that respect. It turns out that supporting add and remove
>   operations to an AC automaton is fairly trivial. For deep tries over a
>   small alphabet, it would not be very time-efficient, but luckily we
>   have a shallow trie over a large alphabet.
>
> We store a hash multimap of each token to every node that uses that
>   token. When we remove a phrase, we start from the last (bottom-most)
>   node. We remove the pointer to the phrase from this bottom-most node.
>   Then, if it has any children, we can't delete any more. Otherwise, go
>   through each other node that uses this node as a fail state and
>   recompute its fail state. Finally, delete the node, then go up to the
>   node's parent and do the same process. We'll eventually reach either a
>   node that has another phrase output, a child, or the root node.
>
> That's kind of difficult to picture, so consider this trie (stolen
>   from the Wikipedia article). We're going to remove the string caa
>   (light gray color), which will require that the fail states in yellow
>   be updated:
>
> [image: trie-before]
>
> The result:
>
> [image: trie-after]
>
> Note there are cases where a node's fail state might be updated 2 or
>   more times in the same remove operation, but will eventually be
>   correct. This could be avoided by removing everything first, then
>   going back through tokens, but the code is complicated enough as it
>   is, and that would only provide a performance benefit in certain
>   awkward circumstances, while being a performance hit in the average
>   case. We just assume that strings containing the same token more than
>   once are rare.
>
> Adding a node is slightly more difficult, but can make use of the same
>   hash multimap structure. Each time a node is added, every other node
>   in the trie that uses the same token and is at a lower depth than the
>   added node could need to have its fail state updated to the new node.
>
> To help picture that, imagine going from the second diagram back to
>   the first diagram. The same two fail states are the ones who would
>   need to be updated if adding the string caa back into that trie, and
>   since we recompute every c and a node, it's not a problem.
>
> We could keep track of the node depths to skip over about half, but
>   right now it's just recomputing the fail state for every node that
>   shares the token to save memory. This means that tries where the
>   tokens appear many times will be slow to add to, but again that's
>   considered a rare enough situation. It would be a concern if you were
>   trying to adapt this technique to something like a DNA sequence or
>   antivirus database where there is a small alphabet.
>
> The time complexity depends on how many nodes share symbols and how
>   deep the trie is, meaning it's worst-case O(N), but in practice a
>   fairly small number (average-case is roughly O(log^2 N) ).

Incredibly messy and mostly uncommented code, but if you're curious, here's [the header](https://gitlab.com/burningmime/setmatch/blob/master/main/src/core/phrase_trie.hpp), [the body](https://gitlab.com/burningmime/setmatch/blob/master/main/src/core/phrase_trie.cpp), and [some tests](https://gitlab.com/burningmime/setmatch/blob/master/main/src/test/phrase_trie_test.cpp)